# Using WS-Security with JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, ws-security, java-metro-framework

Let's pretend all I have is emacs.  I want to implement a web service that uses WS-Security with JAX-WS.  Does anyone know of a good example of implementing a client that does not rely on tools like Netbeans?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The metro stack (which is the reference implementation for jaxws) has a pretty detailed [guide](https://javaee.github.io/metro/doc/user-guide/index.html), and pretty much all the examples have "with netbeans" and "without netbeans" versions (e.g. i think sections 13/14 are what you are looking for).  I know this because I've done a lot of this with emacs myself.  (Note, the metro stack has some enhancements not in the base JDK, so you might need to use it specifically to get that stuff working).